# Split the list in two,where the length of first is given

Tags: prolog

I want to create a function that we split a list in 2 ,given the length of the first one.I really stuck in the beginning of it.

```
split(L,0,[],L).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use length/2 and append/3

Comment: Elegant!  (I refer to previous comment).  The recursive solution is fine, but using length and append is way easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by thinking about trying to describe the result you want. You can break `List` into a `Start` and `End`, and the length of `Start` should be `Length`.

```
split(List, Length, Start, End) :-
    length(Start, Length),
    append(Start, End, List).
```

---

As a note, the order of `length` and `append` will make a difference in efficiency. If `append` were put first, then append would unify `Start` with the first zero elements of `List` and would fail on the length check, then would unify `Start` with the first element, then the first two, then three, and so on until it gets to a prefix of `List` with length `Length`. You can avoid all of these obvious dead ends by placing the `length` goal first, which will start you off with a list of the correct size.

Comment: Nice, but isn't it preferable to exchange those two goals?

Comment: @false It definitely would be. I will swap those around and add an explanation as to why one way is better. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Now, the goal terminates, iff `Length` is known. That is, there is no need that any of the other three is known! Conversely, if `append/3` is the first goal, then termination is more complex: the length of either `List` or `Start` must be known - and further, there are some more exotic cases where it terminates like `List = [a|_], Start = [b|_]`.